# Is Aparapi provide task parallism?

Tags: java, opencl, aparapi

Is aparapi (API in java for Open CL) provides task parallelism or it provides only data parallelism. If provides task parallelism, is it guarantee that tasks will execute on separate devices

Comment: I used it but never did multi-device autmatically. I think it is data parallelism.

Comment: You can adjust reference points and ranges to use data on multiple devices. Not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Aparapi isn't just an API in java for OPENCL, it's a parallel processing library.

You could execute an Aparapi kernel either on your GPU, or your CPU.
If you choose to run an Aparapi kernel on your GPU, but either Aparapi fails to cross compile the kernel for your GPU, or your GPU can't cope with Aparapi's output, it will attempt to fall back to your CPU.
When it does this, it will generate a warning.

Aparapi will only try to run a kernel on a single device, and not on a lot of different devices.
If you intend to do this, you will manually need to decide whether and how you want to do this.

I hope that answers your question.